# How to use variable in Nokogiri contains

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri

I have an XML file like:

```
<main>
  <key>xxx</key>
  <key>yyy</b>
  <key>zzz</key>
</main>
```

To check whether the XML has a node with text "yyy", I can use:

```
xml = Nokogiri::XML(file)
if xml.at('main/key:contains("yyy")')
  #code will go here
end
```

But if the text value is a variable how can I use the same statement?
Note: I have tried below solution and it doesn't work:

```
var = "yyy"
if xml.at("main/key:contains(#{var})")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"main/key:contains(#{var})"
```

interpolates to to

```
"main/key:contains(yyy)"
```

Note the absence of quotes. You want this:

```
"main/key:contains(\"#{var}\")"
```

or more prettily

```
%Q{main/key:contains("#{var}")}
```

and some [clever escaping](http://kushalm.com/the-perils-of-xpath-expressions-specifically-escaping-quotes) would also help if you are not sure about the content of `var`.